# Using Orfeo Toolbox in Google Colab

Tags: python, installation, orfeo-toolbox, otb-applications

[Orfeo Toolbox](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/PythonAPI.html) (OTB) has a tool that I'd like to use for some image processing as part of a longer Python workflow that I'm executing in Google Colab. While OTB can be called via Python if the whole program is installed locally, I can't figure out if there is a way to install OTB's Python tools in a Colab notebook.

Comment: There is a conda for OTB, maybe this can help?

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I don't think Colab has conda, just pip. Can OTB be installed with pip?

Comment: Not for the moment, there is an open issue about pip. you can track any progress by subscribing to this issue on gitlab. https://gitlab.orfeo-toolbox.org/orfeotoolbox/otb/issues/1615